# Import many Excel Files as DataFrames with automatic Name generation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, import

I want to import several files with pandas and assign a specific Name to them
I can do it like this:

```
Data1 = pd.read_excel('Data1.xlsx')
Data2 = pd.read_excel('Data2.xlsx')
```

But with 100 files it takes ages to create the variable names.

My goal is to use a list and do the sames with a loop:

```
List = ['Data1', 'Data2, ...,'Data100]
```

First I tried this:

```
Data1 = pd.read_excel(List[0]+'.xlsx')
```

which worked fine.

The I tried a loop for the names:

```
for name in List:
    List[name] = pd.read_excel(List[0]+'.xlsx')
```

This does not work, due to my Definition of the Name I guess.
What can I do to create the names according to the list, please?

Comment: Don't create 100 separate data frames. Create **one** list or dict of 100 data frames via comprehensions: `df_dict = {name:pd.read_excel(name+'.xlsx') for name in List}`. Easy to recall and use dfs inside a container: `df_dict['Data1']`, `df_dict['Data2']`, ...

Comment: Sounds interesting. I will give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: I tried a little bit around with your tip. Worked great. Thanks a lot. I still have some minor problem, that the whole recall "df_dict['Data1']" is quite long for each name. I would like to give them a short name each, like data1 and data2 to better use them later on. If I have a list, like "[data1, data2 ..] I can't assign the dataframes to those short names?, other wise I need to do data1 = df_dict['Data1'] etc for each dataframe, right?

Comment: I created a dictionary: dictionary = dict(zip(name_list, name_list)); then a loop and it worked fine:
i = 0
while i < x:
    vars()[dictionary[name_liste[i]] = df_dict[name_list[i]]
    i += 1
Guess it's totally inefficient, but I works finaly... still curious how to make this more elegant

Comment: You could run `zip` in the comprehension: `df_dict = {n:pd.read_excel(f+'.xlsx') for n, f in zip(name_list, file_list)}`. Even `enumerate`: `df_dict = {'data'+str(i+1):pd.read_excel(fname+'.xlsx') for i, fname in enumerate(file_list)}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you want to do.

If you are asking how to create variables within the program for each of the values in your list, that is impossible.

I don't know what your data is, or what you are trying to do with it. However, if you need to deal with the files one at a time, you can easily create a `for` loop that performs all operations on one file, then when that file is complete, moves onto the next one. You can easily do this by changing the contents of your list to equal the filenames you want to access.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

list = ['File1', 'File2', 'File3', 'File4']

for name in list:
i = 0
Data = pd.read_excel(list[i] + '.xlsx']
i = i + 1

'Put whatever you want to do with the data here'
```

So if you have a list with the filenames, you can just repurpose your loop. The i variable exists to get the current element of the list -- if the loop has iterated over the code once, i will get the file name at index position 1. Just put whatever you want done to the file where I have placed the comment.

Comment: I need the Data of your code "Data = pd.read_excel(list[i] + '.xlsx']" to change. I need a "Data1, Data2 etc" Because I will work with each of the Data independentely later on.